# ITextSharp pdf resize and data alignment

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, itext

I am using ITextSharp to convert HTML to PDF but i want the PDF to be generated of size 5cm width. I used the following code

```
var pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(2.05f, 2.05f);
Document doc = new Document(pgSize);
```

but it is just resizing the pdf and my data disappeared in the pdf or get hide.
How can i align the data in the center in PDF or resize the pdf? Here is my code
    public void ConvertHTMLToPDF(string HTMLCode)
        {

```
        try
        {
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);

            StringReader reader = new StringReader(HTMLCode);

            var pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(2.05f, 2.05f);                
            Document doc = new Document(pgSize);
            HTMLWorker parser = new HTMLWorker(doc);

            PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(Server.MapPath("~") + "/App_Data/HTMLToPDF.pdf",
            FileMode.Create));
            doc.Open();
            foreach (IElement element in HTMLWorker.ParseToList(
            new StringReader(HTMLCode), null))
            {

                doc.Add(element);
            }

            doc.Close();
            Response.End();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom page size in iTextSharp in C#.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17079021/custom-page-size-in-itextsharp-in-c-net)

Comment: You shouldn't use `HTMLWorker`. See https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml and since when is 2.05 pt equal to 5cm?

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a PDF that measures 0.0723 cm by 0.0723 cm. That is much too small to add any content. If you want to create a PDF of 5 cm by 5 cm, you need to create your document like this:

```
var pgSize = new iTextSharp.text.Rectangle(141.732f, 141.732f);
Document doc = new Document(pgSize);
```

As for the alignment, that should be defined in the HTML, but you are using an old version of iText and you are using the deprecated `HTMLWorker`.

You should upgrade to iText 7 and pdfHTML as described here: [Converting HTML to PDF using iText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/converting-html-to-pdf-using-itext/47896272#47896272)

Also: the size of the page can be defined in the `@page`-rule of the CSS. See [Huge white space after header in PDF using Flying Saucer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47845552/huge-white-space-after-header-in-pdf-using-flying-saucer/47847427#47847427)

Why would you make it difficult for yourself by using an old iText version, when the new version allows you to do this:

```
@page {
  size: 5cm 5cm;
}
```