# How to set PDF page size A4 when we use ITextRenderer to generate PDF from thymeleaf HTML template?

Tags: java, itext, thymeleaf, itext7

How to set PDF page size A4 when we use ITextRenderer to generate PDF from thymeleaf HTML template ?

I have generated PDF but page size is not proper, how to set page size A4 ITextRenderer library in JAVA

```
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver templateResolver = new 
    ClassLoaderTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");

    TemplateEngine templateEngine = new TemplateEngine();
    templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);

    Context context = new Context();
    context.setVariable("name", "Thomas");

    String html = templateEngine.process("templates/Quote", context);

    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("message.pdf");
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();
    renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
    renderer.layout();
    renderer.createPDF(outputStream,true);
    outputStream.close();
```

Comment: You mention `ITextRenderer`. This means that you are using Flying Saucer, a 3rd party product that uses an obsolete version of iText [that should no longer be used in production](https://developers.itextpdf.com/question/versions-older-than-5) and that most certainly doesn't use iText 7 (if it does, it's doing something illegal). If you want to use iText 7, read [Converting HTML to PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895935/converting-html-to-pdf-using-itext); also read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48018716/itextsharp-pdf-resize-and-data-alignment/48021729#48021729).

Answer (score 6):

Please be aware that you are using `FlyingSaucer`, not `iText`.
`FlyingSaucer` is a product that internally uses (a very old version of) `iText`.

You are immediately cutting yourself off from 10+ years of bugfixes and developments.

If you are comfortable going for just `iText`, the best way of solving this issue is with pdfHTML.

It's an add-on we wrote to the iText7 core library that is specifically designed to convert HTML into PDF.

Simple example:

```
    File src = new File("source_html_file.html");
    File dest = new File("target_pdf_file.pdf");

    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    Document doc = new Document(pdf, PageSize.A4);
    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(src);

    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    FontProvider dfp = new DefaultFontProvider(true, true, true);
    converterProperties.setFontProvider(dfp);

    HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(stream, pdf, converterProperties);
```

Check out the tutorials online for more information
https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-examples/itext-7-converting-html-pdf

Comment: Note that defining `PageSize.A4` the way you do in your code can be ignored if there's an `@page` definition of the page size on the CSS level.

Comment: Very true. In order to be completely sure that any incoming HTML and CSS is ok, you can parse it with JSoup however, and remove those conflicting properties.

Answer (score 1):

To fix this issue using jsoup, xhtmlrenderer from flying-saucer-pdf-openpdf just set this in your html-document:

```
@page {
    size: A4;
}
```