# itext7 doesn't break long url

Tags: html, pdf, itext

I'm trying to generate a PDF file from HTML. I have two long URL in the HTML code. The problem is that just one URL (`longURL2`) is split to the next line. The other URL (`longURL`) exceeds the page margin. Could someone help me to figure out why iText does not split the other URL?

My code:

```
String longURL = "http://localhost/erp/process/see_process.jsp?vp=ATENDING_PROCESS_EMPLOYEE&amp;tr=1493131180671041&amp;ev=1520277948136217";
String longURL2 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48422409/how-to-set-pdf-page-size-a4-when-we-use-itextrenderer-to-generate-pdf-from-thyme";

String htmlCode = 
              "<p align=\"right\">City Name - March, 5 \r\n2018.</p>"
            + "<p>&nbsp;</p>"
            + "<p>&nbsp;Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus sollicitudin consectetur vulputate. "
            + "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus."
            + "<br/><br/></p>"
            + "<p>" + longURL + "</p>"
            + "<p>" + longURL2 + "</p>"
            + "<p>&nbsp;</p>"
            + "<p>&nbsp;</p><center>"
            + "<p><b>My First Name \r\nLast Name</b><br>My Department</p>"
            + "</center>";

File dest = new File("C:/Temp/target_pdf_file.pdf");

PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
pdf.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);

ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
FontProvider dfp = new DefaultFontProvider(true, true, true);
converterProperties.setFontProvider(dfp);

HtmlConverter.convertToPdf(htmlCode, pdf, converterProperties);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I've figured out. The problem is the characters used by iText to split lines. It doesn't use characters like "_". So, first of all, it is necessary to add this character. A good approach is to extend the class `DefaultSplitCharacters`. The code is as follow:

```
public class CustomSplitCharacters extends DefaultSplitCharacters {

    @Override
    public boolean isSplitCharacter(GlyphLine text, int glyphPos) {

        if (super.isSplitCharacter(text, glyphPos)) return true;

        int charCode = text.get(glyphPos).getUnicode();

        return (charCode == '_' || charCode == '&' || charCode == '?' ||
                charCode == '='); 
    }
}
```

Note that I've added some extra split characters: `"&", "?" and "="`.

The second step is to use the `HtmlConverter` to generate the pdf. The code is as follow:

```
    File dest = new File("C:/Temp/target_pdf_file.pdf");

    PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(dest));
    pdf.setDefaultPageSize(PageSize.A4);

    ConverterProperties converterProperties = new ConverterProperties();
    FontProvider dfp = new DefaultFontProvider(true, true, true);
    converterProperties.setFontProvider(dfp);
    converterProperties.setImmediateFlush(false);

    Document doc = HtmlConverter.convertToDocument(htmlCode, pdf , converterProperties);
    doc.setProperty(Property.SPLIT_CHARACTERS, new CustomSplitCharacters());
    doc.relayout();

    doc.close();
```